# Что произойдёт, если даже метод main пробросит исключение?

Tags: java, исключения, методы, main

Допустим, метод main вызывает метод `go()`, метод `go()` вызывает метод `run()`, метод `run()` выбрасывает исключение, метод `go()` его пробрасывает, метод `main()` тоже пробрасывает, что произойдёт в этом случае?

Comment: исполнение программы будет прерванно с выводом в лог, что ж ещё))

Comment: Напишите соответствующий код, запустите да посмотрите на результат)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Коротко:**

1. В [стандартный вывод ошибок (stderr)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8#%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA) будет выведено сообщение об ошибке, в котором будет указано имя потока и трассировка стека исключения.
2. Если нет запущенных потоков-недемонов, то программа будет завершена, иначе программа будет ждать завершения всех таких потоков.

**Длинно:**

Что происходит с необработанным исключением написано в документации ([§11.3. Run-Time Handling of an Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3)):

> **§11.3. Run-Time Handling of an Exception**
>
> ...
>
> **If no catch clause that can handle an exception can be found, then the current thread (the thread that encountered the exception) is terminated.** Before termination, all finally clauses are executed and the uncaught exception is handled according to the following rules:
>
> - If the current thread has an uncaught exception handler set, then that handler is executed.
> - Otherwise, the method uncaughtException is invoked for the ThreadGroup that is the parent of the current thread. If the ThreadGroup and its parent ThreadGroups do not override uncaughtException, **then the default handler's uncaughtException method is invoked.**
>
> **§11.3. Обработка исключений времени выполнения**
>
> ...
>
> **Если конструкций `catch`, способная обработать сгенерированное исключение не найдена, то текущий поток выполнения (поток, в котором сгенерировано исключение), завершается.** Перед завершением выполняются все конструкции finally, а неперехваченное исключение обрабатывается в соответствии со следующими правилами.
>
> - Если текущий поток имеет установленный обработчик неперехваченных исключений, вызывается этот обработчик.
> - В противном случае для группы `ThreadGroup`, которая представляет собой родителя текущего потока, вызывается метод `uncaughtException`. Если `ThreadGroup` и ее родительские `ThreadGroup` не перекрывают `uncaughtException`, **то вызывается метод `uncaughtException` обработчика по умолчанию.**

Для случая с методом `main` произойдет две вещи:

1. будет завершен главный поток приложения;
2. будет вызван [`ThreadGroup.uncaughtException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException(java.lang.Thread,java.lang.Throwable)).

Первое приведет к остановке программы целиком, если главный поток — единственный поток-недемон, оставшийся в живых ([§12.8. Program Exit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.8)):

> A program terminates all its activity and exits when one of two things happens:
>
> - All the threads that are not daemon threads terminate.

Поведение глобально обработчика по умолчанию может быть переопределено, но по умолчанию он выведет имя потока выполнения и трассировку стека исключения в стандартный поток ошибок ([`ThreadGroup.uncaughtException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException(java.lang.Thread,java.lang.Throwable))):

> ...  Otherwise, a message containing the thread's name, as returned from the thread's getName method, and a stack backtrace, using the Throwable's printStackTrace method, is printed to the standard error stream.